# Can someone help me in jquery addition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to give points to my users who submit articles based on their articles word count.

But my page has many text area fields. Lets say message1,message2,message3

When the user fill textarea(message1,message2,message3) it will show like this in the bottom.

```
You have typed x words. Points per word : 0.2. Estimated point: xx
```

I also want to calculate overall points. So i would like to add points of message1,message2,message3 and display it as overall points.

I'm a jquery noob. So i'm not sure which variable i should call.

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/yZb7w/29/) code what i have so far.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: well, one option is to concatenate all inputs from the text fields (separating them with spaces) and then calculate the points from that string. This will work if all the text areas will have the same points per word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're not storing the scores from the individual text area fields so you have no values to add up for the total score.  After you start storing this data, you just have to update the total score area when any of the individual scores change.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFDQ3/6/

Comment: Awesome.. One more thing. I see 0.6000000000000001 when multiply 3 x 0.2. Can you tell me how to fix this? I want only 0.6. Very much thanks

Comment: fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/NFDQ3/5/ - you just have to format the number, which i did with myNumber.toFixed(2) to keep it to 2 decimal places. just change that argument to a 1 to get just one decimal place like you want

Comment: But i still see 0.6000000000000001 in your file. :(

Comment: I only made the change on the output for the total.  Updated all output values here:  http://jsfiddle.net/NFDQ3/6/

Answer (score 2):

you can declare a variable to save the value of each word count (initialized in 0):

```
var count1 = count2 = count3 = 0;
```

And then do something like:

```
count1 = data.words;
$('#showData4').html((count1+count2+count3)*0.2);
```

For each `$('#testTextarea').textareaCount()` you have, as you can see on this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/pqMBW/)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the count of every Textfield in an array that you can use to compute the overall sum.

I've edited your code, see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yZb7w/38/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see 0.6000000000000001 when multiply 3 x 0.2. Can you tell me how to fix this? I want only 0.6. Very much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have something like:

```
  $('#testTextarea3').textareaCount(options3, function(data){
                $('#showData3').html("You have typed <b>" + data.words + "</b> words. Points per word : <b> 0.2</b>. Estimated point: <b>" + (0.2 * data.words) +"</b>");
                 $(this).data("points",(0.2 * data.words));

            });
```

This will store the points value per testTextarea. The next step you will do is have a totalScore textarea or some updating behavior for some component and extract stored scored from all the textAreas like:

```
   $('#testTextarea3').data("points");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger an event from inside `getInfo`, then bind to that event from outside your plugin to get the updated count from each textarea. Then, it's just a matter of keeping track of each count and adding them up. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4h7X/1/) (info object will be logged to the console).